# connecting to sql server via vba/odbc

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc

I'm not sure what is wrong with my code here, it is not throwing any errors and is compiling successfully. However, the recordset is not grabbing any data. Nothing is being pasted into the sheet. The query itself runs fine from command line/sqlserver. Do I need to add a dsn somewhere in the connection string?

```
Sub queryTest()

Dim connection As New ADODB.connection
Dim recordset As ADODB.recordset
Dim strSQL As New ADODB.Command

connection.Open "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=xxx;" & _
       "trusted_connection=yes;DATABASE=xxxx"

strSQL.ActiveConnection = connection
strSQL.CommandText = "SELECT TOP (50) [CalendarSK] ,[CalendarMonthSK] ,[CalendarDate] FROM [xxxx].[dbo].[tblCalendar]"
strSQL.CommandType = adCmdText

Set recordset = strSQL.Execute

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").CopyFromRecordset recordset

recordset.Close
connection.Close


End Sub
```

Comment: use the debugger: is there anything in the recordset? work backwards...

Comment: No, there is nothing in the recordset so I imagine the problem is in my connection string? There is nothing wrong with the query.

Comment: what happens if you remove "[xxxx]." from query?  what do you get when you run "SELECT TOP (50) [CalendarSK] ,[CalendarMonthSK] ,[CalendarDate] FROM [dbo].[tblCalendar]" in SSMS?

Comment: Thanks Mitch, that query works in ssms, my problem was I needed to add a dsn in my connection string.

Comment: a dsn is a solution but it's possible without. check "Syntax without DSN" https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-odbc?view=sql-server-ver15